# CommandLineParser library - How to use output of one option into next one

Tags: c#, command-line, cmd, command-line-arguments, command-line-parser

I am reading the CommandLineParser documentation and I am very interested in the way functionality is designed here:

[CommandLine for verbs](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline#for-verbs)

I basically have a command line application where I need to set different parameters. Something like below

> MyApp.exe -a val1 -b val2 -c -d

What I am trying to achieve is that if -c is present in the command line application, I want to take the result of what **-a val1 -b val2** produced and then call my next function with that result and the operation that **-c** does.

In this case:

```
int Main(string[] args) {
  return CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments<AddOptions, CommitOptions, CloneOptions>(args)
    .MapResult(
      (AddOptions opts) => RunAddAndReturnExitCode(opts),
      (CommitOptions opts) => RunCommitAndReturnExitCode(opts), 
      errs => 1);
}
```

How can I get the result of **RunAddAndReturnExitCode(opts)** and add it into RunCommitAndReturnExitCode?

I really like how the verbs are designed since it keeps the code nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the anonymous delegate if you are using named static methods.

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    return 
        Parser.Default.ParseArguments<SubmitProcessOptions, CancelProcessOptions, GetProcessOptions>(args)
            .MapResult<SubmitProcessOptions, CancelProcessOptions, GetProcessOptions, int>(
                RunSubmitProcess,
                RunCancelProcess,
                RunGetProcess,
                HandleParseError);
}

static int RunSubmitProcess(SubmitProcessOptions submitProcessOptions)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ProcessKey: {submitProcessOptions.ProcessKey}");
    foreach (var parameter in submitProcessOptions.Parameters)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Parameter: {parameter}");
    }
    return 0;
}

static int RunCancelProcess(CancelProcessOptions cancelProcessOptions)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ProcessKey: {cancelProcessOptions.ProcessKey}");
    return 0;
}

static int RunGetProcess(GetProcessOptions getProcessOptions)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ProcessKey: {getProcessOptions.ProcessKey}");
    return 0;
}

static int HandleParseError(IEnumerable<Error> errs)
{
    //handle errors
    return 1;
}
```